# AT Command for receiving automatic SMS notification

Tags: c#, sms, at-command, sms-gateway, hyperterminal

I have 2 gprs/gsm modems with me at the moment one of them is huawei and the other is a prolink modem. I have no problem sending or receiving SMSes via AT Commands. However I am trying to receive automatic notification using this command AT+CNMI and I am not able to get it to work but when I try this command the modem replies with ok with no errors.

Procedures that I have performed so far

1. Tried numerous combination for the AT+CNMI commands 2,1,0,0,0, 2,2,0,0,0 and etc but to no avail
2. I have set the preferred message storage to sim card and I am able to receive message and extract it as well using various AT commands.

I tried in hyperterminal as well as using C sharp but to no avail. The built software that comes with the modem are able to receive the notification. Can someone guide me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure out the problem already :) . Basically the modem that i used makes use of several different ports and the new message notification will be received by another port. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Many of these types of devices use different commands.  Some use proprietary commands.  Since it works fine with the included software, I would recommend figuring out how that works.

The easiest way to do this is to fire up some [free serial port monitoring software](http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/).  Once you get it set up, start up the software the device came with and see what commands it sends.  Then, you can use those same commands yourself.

Comment: I tried Serial Port Monitor by eltima software did not help much as they gave a lot of low level info. And i also need to get it to work with several type of GSM modem so i have stick with AT Commands. If i cannot get the notification method to work i will resort to the polling method to check for new message in the modem. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't need the low-level view.  I think they call it a "request view" or something like that which shows the data being sent and received.  No need to look at all of the IOCTL stuff.  You are looking for the AT commands that the software is sending.

Comment: I tried almost around 5 other free software but still not able to see any AT commands during monitoring. All i see is a lot of low level information and i tried all the views avaliable in the software. Anyway i have solved the problem. Many thanks for your help.