# Automatically receiving mobile phone's SMS to hyperterminal

Tags: gsm, at-command

I'm experimenting with AT commands on hyperterminal and my cellphone as the GSM modem. I'm using an LG-C305 and so far I've been able to use a lot of AT commands succesfully. The one that I'm having a lot of trouble with is receiving SMS automatically on hyperterminal.

I can send SMS from hyperterminal, read SMS that are already on the phone, etc. What I can not do is to receive a new SMS directly to the hyperterminal or at least a notification that a new SMs has been received.

Someone asked the exact same question here, but the way he solved the problem is not working for me and I don't know how to contact him, here's the link to his question:

[AT Command for receiving automatic SMS notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980625/question-regarding-at-command-receiving-automatic-notification)

When I get a call on my phone, hyperterminal notificates me about it, which means the connection is alright, that should not be the problem.

The AT command that is supposed to do the trick is AT+CNMI, but I've used it a lot of times, with all sorts of combinations (AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0 / AT+CNMI=1,1,0,0,0 / etc) and none has worked.

Any input would be greatly appreciated, thankk in advance.

Comment: have you tried `2,2,0,1,0`?

Answer (score 0):

Set: `at+cnmi=2,1` then when an sms comes in the phone will send: `+CMTI: "ME",n`  where `n` is the storage number. Use `n` in `at+cmgr=n` to read the message.